# Custom loss function and fit data for multiple inputs and outputs in tf.Keras

Tags: python, tf.keras, loss-function, multiple-input

I am working around with a DNN in tf.Keras, which looks like as follows:

```
# Construct the DNN model with 2 inputs, 2 outputs and 3 hidden layers
c0_input = Input(shape=(1,), name="c0")
c1_input = Input(shape=(1,), name="c1")

# Concatenate the input into one layer
tensor_input = Concatenate(axis=-1)([c0_input, c1_input])
hidden_1 = Dense(100)(tensor_input)
activation_1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(hidden_1)
hidden_2 = Dense(100)(activation_1)
activation_2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(hidden_2)
hidden_3 = Dense(100)(activation_2)
activation_3 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(hidden_3)

# 2 outputs are named as x0 and x1
x0_output = Dense(1, name="x0")(activation_3)
x1_output = Dense(1, name="x1")(activation_3)

# The model
DNN_model = Model(inputs=[c0_input, c1_input], outputs=[x0_output, x1_output])
```

As you can see, this DNN has 2 inputs `(c0, c1)` and 2 outputs `(x0, x1)`. The loss function I am aiming at is: `c0 * (x0 - x1**2)**2 + c1 * (x1 - c0 * x0)**2`, which includes the both inputs and the both outputs. Here are my questions:

- How can I write a loss function, which takes into account all `c0, c1, x0, x1` ? I have tried to work around with the custom loss function in Keras, but it looks like it is not correct to slice and extract `x0` and `x1` from `y_pred` (which should be a part of the loss function).
- How can I fit the training data ? In this case we have an array training data for `c0` and another for `c1`.
- If this is hard to achieve with Keras, is there any recommendation for any other packages which are easier to deal with ?

Many thanks for reading and answering my question. I have tried to play with custom loss and weight loss, but it doesn't seem to help so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate` class and setting `axis=-1` and `trainable=False` will fix your problem.
I too have the same experience of writing a custom loss function for multi inputs and multi outputs.

**Here are changes I made to your existing code**

```
c0_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name="c0")
c1_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name="c1")

# Concatenate the input into one layer
tensor_input = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([c0_input, c1_input])
hidden_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)(tensor_input)
activation_1 =  tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(hidden_1)
hidden_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)(activation_1)
activation_2 =  tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(hidden_2)
hidden_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)(activation_2)
activation_3 =  tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(hidden_3)

# 2 outputs are named as x0 and x1
x0_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="x0")(activation_3)
x1_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="x1")(activation_3)
#Here is the main code part
concat_output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1,trainable=False)([c0_input,c1_input,x0_output,x1_output])
# The model
DNN_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[c0_input, c1_input], outputs=[concat_output])
DNN_model.compile(loss=custom_multi_loss,optimizer='adam')
```

**Custom code function**

```
#c0 * (x0 - x1**2)**2 + c1 * (x1 - c0 * x0)**2
def custom_multi_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    c0 = y_pred[0][0]
    c1 = y_pred[0][1]
    x0 = y_pred[0][2]
    x1 = y_pred[0][3]
    x0_true = y_true[0][0] #Not defined in your request
    x1_true = y_true[0][1] #Not defined in your request
    return  c0 * (x0 - x1**2)**2 + c1 * (x1 - c0 * x0)**2
```

**Generate dummy data to test**

```
c0_inp = tf.random.uniform(minval=0.0,maxval=1.0,shape=(4,1))
c1_inp = tf.random.uniform(minval=0.0,maxval=1.0,shape=(4,1))
x0_x1_output = tf.random.uniform(minval=0.0,maxval=1.0,shape=(4,2))
c0_inp,c1_input,x0_x1_output
```

**Fitting model:**

```
DNN_model.fit([c0_inp,c1_inp],x0_x1_output,epochs=2)
```

**Predict code:**

```
DNN_model.predict([c0_inp,c1_inp])
```

**Tested code..**

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I have a query regarding this implementation. How can you use loss weight distribution for this with a custom loss weight modifier?
Also, training will only show the loss and accuracy for concat_output layer! How to check matrices for each actual output layer? 

Thanks